# why COLCARDF Field on SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS equal 0 after runstat on tablespace?

Tags: mainframe, cardinality, db2-zos

i working with db2 10.1 zos
When Runstat on table ، COLCARDF ّfield of SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS One of the columns 0
But on table SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES Fields FIRSTKEYCARDF and FULLKEYCARDF is true

my Runstat jcl job :

RUNSTATS TABLESPACE dbname.tsname part n
TABLE(ALL)
INDEX(schema.ixname)
REPORT NO
SHRLEVEL CHANGE
UPDATE ALL
HISTORY ALL

The table has more than 10 billion data points.
There is also a composite index and a regular index on the column whose cardinality is zero.

Thank you for your help.....

Answer (score 0):

Your runstats job shows the PART keyword which indicates it's collecting statistics at a partition level only.  SYSCOLUMNS records information for the whole object and not just a single partition.  Since a generic column could have the same value in multiple partitions, COLCARDF cannot easily be determined at a partition level.  SYSINDEXES is similar, but for partitioning indexes each key value can only exist in a single partition by definition.

You might be interested in the FORCEROLLUP option of the [RUNSTATS command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/ugref/src/tpc/db2z_runstatssyntax.html) which indicates to DB2 whether to force the aggregation of statistics even if some partitions have no statistics collected.

It's also important to note that without statistics collected on all partitions, the aggregated statistics may be misleading such that Db2 selects a poor access path for queries.  Of course, this is also likely to occur when Db2 thinks the column cardinality (COLCARDF) is zero.

Summary: the best bet is to collect statistics on all partitions (at which point FORCEROLLUP doesn't matter), but if you need the aggregation in the interim the FORCEROLLUP option of RUNSTATS will do that.